# GIF File in splash screen Ionic

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I am developing a hybrid application with ionic-framework and Cordova plugins. They asked me the splash screen on both operating systems (iOS and Android) has a small animation. I imagine a GIF but not if you can load a GIF as splash screen. Or if there is a plugin for this.

Comment: If you want to include gif in your screen then you can refer this link http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/

Comment: Hi, please share the answer if you were able to achieve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way without using plugins. [More information is available here](http://www.gajotres.net/using-views-events-to-create-javascript-pure-ionic-splash-screen/).

HTML

```
 <body>
       <div id="custom-overlay"><img src="http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dancing-banana.gif"></div> 
      <!-- Here comes rest of the content -->
    </body>
```

www/css/**style.css**

```
#custom-overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fe201f;
}

#custom-overlay img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}
```

www/js/**app.js**

```
 .run(function($ionicPlatform, $state, $cordovaSplashscreen) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(navigator.splashscreen) {
        $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
      } 
      });
    });

 .controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("custom-overlay").style.display = "none";      
    }, 3000);
  });  
});
```

Comment: Hello

In my case , will assume i implement you code :

-This Splash loaded ,
- ListCtrl page will show for short time ( milli second ) 
- custom splash screen  show 
- List Ctrl page show.