# IONIC 3, How to change the default spinner on the splash screen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Is there any way I can change the default **spinner** on the splash screen of an ionic 3 app with a **gif spinner**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIF File in splash screen Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349581/gif-file-in-splash-screen-ionic)

Comment: I don't think so, since that speaks about splash screen not the spinner

Answer (score 1):

I needed to resolve same problem and found the answer by [robbannn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783706/robbannn) here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479531

Add this to your config.xml-file:

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

[Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#preferences) are some more preferences you can make use of.